# FTPS, 550 Requested action not take

Tags: ftp, ftps

I need to get access till FTPS server with correct login/pass/CA
This server accept FTP and FTPS modes. I have tested on FTP and everything works ( put, get ), but when I have switched to FTPS on put command error happens:

```
 550 Requested action not taken.
         File unavailable (e.g., file not found, no access).
```

Any ideas ?

Comment: Could you post a bit more of the server log to see what command was issued before you got this error?  Does this error happen immediately when you connect?   It seems like some command is being issued, but without more of the status log it is hard to determine why you are getting this message.

Comment: I didn't have access till server logs. I have tested from another PC, it works. Probably problems somewhere in the middle. BTW, FTPS works in Passive mode !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some old FTP server doesn't support STOR /somefile syntax, you need to set CWD / and only then STOR somefile.